# How to (log) transform *args arguments without losing structure

Tags: python, scipy, variable-length

I am attempting to apply statistical tests to some datasets with variable numbers of groups. This causes a problem when I try to perform a log transformation for said groups while maintaining the ability to perform the test function (in this case scipy's `kruskal()`), which takes a variable number of arguments, one for each group of data.

The code below is an idea of what I want. Naturally `stats.kruskal([np.log(i) for i in args])` does not work, as `kruskal()` does not expect a list of arrays, but one argument for each array. How do I perform log transformation (or any kind of alteration, really), while still being able to use the function?

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np


def t(*args):
    test = stats.kruskal([np.log(i) for i in args])
    return test


a = [11, 12, 4, 42, 12, 1, 21, 12, 6]
b = [1, 12, 4, 3, 14, 8, 8, 6]
c = [2, 2,  3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8]

print(t(a, b, c))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, `*` in front of the list you are forming while calling `kruskal` should do the trick:

```py
test = stats.kruskal(*[np.log(i) for i in args])
```

Asterisk unpacks the list and passes each entry of the list as arguments to the function being called i.e. `kruskal` here.